# Spring AspectJ fails when double-proxying interface: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'm using Spring's `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy  />` to proxy some [JPA repository](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) interfaces.

However, the proxying is failing with the following `Cannot subclass final class class $Proxy80`:

> Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class $Proxy80]: Common
>   causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible
>   class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot
>   subclass final class class $Proxy80

As the error, and a quick google, suggests - this occurs when the proxy target is a final class.  However, in this chain, there are no classes - only interfaces.  Spring generates all the implementations at runtime.

Here's the definition of the interface that's failing:

```
public interface AuthorDAO extends
    CrossStoreJpaRepository<Author,Long>, CrossStoreQueryDslPredicateExecutor<Author> {

}
```

Note I'm using a custom subclass of spring's [JpaRepository](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html) and [QueryDslPredicateExecutor](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.html?is-external=true), defined as follows:

```
public interface CrossStoreJpaRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends JpaRepository<T, ID> {}
public interface CrossStoreQueryDslPredicateExecutor<T> extends QueryDslPredicateExecutor<T>{}
```

Elsewhere, I define custom aspects for methods on these interfaces:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class DocumentLoadingAspect extends AbstractDocumentAspect {

    @Around("execution(* com.mangofactory.crossstore.repository.CrossStore*.find*(..))")
    public Object loadCrossStoreEntity(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable
    {
         // implementation omitted
    }
```

I've confirmed that it's these `@Aspect` definitions that are causing the problem by removing them and re-running the app.

What is causing this error?  It seems to be that proxying a proxy is failing for some reason.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this? I'm getting the same error when on the Integration Gateway interface.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that Spring data JPA creates the repo implementation as a Java proxy which is **final** and then `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />` attempts to to create another proxy per your aspect using cglib subclassing which won't work. Is `proxy-target-class` set to `true` on the autoproxy element?